# Python Reversing Certain Parts of Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Suppose i have the following tuple as:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
```

What i want to do is reversing certain parts of the tuple.

For example 4 elements stays same and then 4 elements will be reversed.

I want to get the following result:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,8,7,6,5,9,10,11,12,16,15,14,13,17,18,19,20)
```

How can i achieve that (as pythonian kind of way)?

Thanks...

Comment: It's not a list, it's a tuple...

Comment: You cannot modify a tuple because tuples are immutable. You can create a new tuple by taking slices of the original tuple and combining them. The use of slices is well-documented, google it.

Comment: I'd use the `itertools` `grouper` recipe to chunk the tuple into fours, reverse every other result, then chain them back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, however, by converting `a` to a `list`, in-place assignment can be performed:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
new_a = list(a)
for c, i in enumerate(range(0, len(a), 4)):
  if c%2: 
     new_a[i:i+4] = new_a[i:i+4][::-1]

print(tuple(new_a))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct, simple, readable answer (pythonic?):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

for n in range(0, len(a), 8):
    a[n+4:n+8] = a[n+7:n+3:-1]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generator-based solution.  The benefits of doing it this way is that this solution doesn't require the input to be sliceable, so you can apply it to the output of functions like `zip` and `map`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zipl
from itertools import cycle, chain

_marker = object()

def cycle_map(iterable, func_iterable):
    funcs = cycle(func_iterable)
    for func, item in zip(funcs, iterable):
        if func:
            yield func(item)
        else:
            yield item

def reverse_filter(iterable, remove=_marker):
    t = tuple(i for i in iterable if i is not remove)
    return reversed(t)

def reverse_alternating(iterable, length=4):
    chunks = zipl(*[iter(iterable)]*length, fillvalue=_marker)
    funcs = (None, reverse_filter) 
    return chain.from_iterable(cycle_map(chunks, funcs))

a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
list(reverse_alternating(a))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
res = [a[v:v+4] if i%2 == 0 else list(reversed(a[v:v+4])) for i, v in enumerate(range(0, len(a), 4))]
print(tuple(chain.from_iterable(res)))    #Flatten list
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to approach the problem using list comprehension (not the fastest probably). Wanted to share the logic, assuming that `len(a)` is divisible by `4`:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
lst = [a[j:j+4] if i%2 == 0 else a[j:j+4][::-1] for i, j in 
enumerate(range(0,len(a), 4))]
result = tuple([j for i in lst for j in i])
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```